# Angular CLI - the ng serve proxy no longer works as it did before

Tags: angular, proxy, angular-cli

In beta 24 of Angular-CLI, the dist folder was built, now in beta 31 it seems that the dist folder is no longer built when doing an ng serve.

This is creating a problem for me because I serve the whole app up in an express app that is part of my project.  I needed to do this because I have a template that modifies the base href.

Before I had a proxy-config file set up as:

```
{
  "/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

This worked before because the dist folder was being created and the express app was looking in this folder for the files.

But now since this folder is not there, it cannot find any of the files.

I was thinking that maybe I could set it up to just proxy the api calls but so I setup the proxy-config file like this:

```
{
  "/analytics/api-dev": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000/analytics/api-dev",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

But when I do this, I get a 404 when it tries to go to:
POST http://localhost:4200/analytics/api-dev

I'm surprised its not proxying that request to 3000:
http://localhost:3000/analytics/api-dev

NOTE: for this I have my base ref set to:

```
<base href="/">
```

Is it possible to setup the proxy config file to only proxy the API calls but nothing else?

If I can do this, I might be able to find another way around the problem of setting the base href in the html.

THANKS!!!

Comment: Why don't you just use `ng build --base-href x`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this by using `ng watch` instead of `ng serve`

Comment: `ng watch` doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry, I meant ng build --watch